# Pasting time-formatted cells changes their values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have time durations (in seconds) stored in cells that are formatted as Custom, namely "[sss].0", that are displayed like this:

[image]

I'd like to edit some of those values, but hitting F2 shows me a value different from the one displayed earlier:

[image]

If I change the cells' format to number, text or general, the cells are replaced with non-sensical numbers with lots of decimals. The same happens if I paste those cells elsewhere, with the options Values Only.

I would just like to have a copy of the cell values that I actually see displayed in the sheet ("what you see"). How can I achieve this given that (as it seems) the real cell values underneath, or their format, have somehow become corrupted?

Comment: Clearly you need to format the target cell with the  same format as the source cell ...

Comment: No. What I need to do is edit the values as they are displayed, e.g. edit the 008.4 into 008.5; I cannot do this with the current cell formatting, however, and changing to other formats does not help, as I explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither the value nor the custom format have become corrupted.  But editing a time format cell does not necessarily show you the custom formatted value while you are editing.  That custom format is only applied after the cell has been edited.

In your particular example, the format being used when you edit is `hh:mm:ss`, so you could change `00:00:08`  to `00:00:08.5` and you should see the properly custom formatted value after you confirm the edit.

Mostly, with dates and times, what you enter; the value stored; and the value displayed can all be different.  Excel stores date/time as days and fractions of a day since `1/1/1900`.  So the value stored for `8.4` seconds would be `9.72222E-05`.

If it is simpler, you could store in that cell, for example:

```
=8.4/86400
```

If you then wanted to change it to 8.5, editing would bring up that formula, and you could easily change it to

```
=8.5/86400
```

*There are 86,400 seconds in a day*